# Generic way to read all documents types programmatically

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I am using the code below to read content of files from SharePoint 2019 On premise server. This code only work for word document though, Is there a generic code that will allow me to read other document type like PDF,PowerPoint,Excel etc

```
                File file = clientContext.Web.GetFileByUrl(resultRow["Path"].ToString());
                stream = file.OpenBinaryStream();
                clientContext.Load(file);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();



                WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream.Value, false);

                Body body = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

                int bodylength = body.InnerText.Length;
```

Comment: Of course there isn't. You would have to first determine the magic number (first bytes) and use it to determine the *possible* file type: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures  e.g. PK means "ZIP file", so this *could* be a docx, xlsx, pptx... You would then unzip and look for a subfolder "word", "xl" or "ppt" to know what you are dealing with. More important though: **why** would you do such a thing? To search across multiple file types maybe? There are better ways to do that.

Comment: @LocEngineer yes am searching content through multiple file..what better ways are you referring to?

Comment: You could let SharePoint do the work for you, i.e. use crawl: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/manage-crawling

Comment: @LocEngineer this is exactly what i did,i have let SharePoint search for a word for me and got back the file path. Now am opening each file to get the paragraph where that word exist. Note I cant use HitHighlightsummary which starts only from the top and has a length of max 10000.. Am i missing something here?